# Why does $_.Name include full path when within quotes in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

When I run this in powershell it outputs the name of my files (in this case just one), without full path:

```
PS C:\dev\temp> gci test.* | % { $_.Name }
test.txt
```

When I put the name in quotes for string formatting it includes the full path:

```
PS C:\dev\temp> gci test.* | % { "Name is: $_.Name" }
Name is: C:\dev\temp\test.txt.Name
```

What crazy magic is going on here? How can I get the name without full path and use it in quotes for formatting? I could use `"blah " + $_.Name + " blah"` but that seems uglier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Powershell automatically expands variables in double quotes. Instead of returning the name propery of your object it returns what it thinks is the value you need.

If you want to select the name attribute you can do it like this:

```
gci test.* | % { "Name: $($_.Name)" }
```

This forces Powershell to evaluate the expression in the braces first so that it only concatenates your string and the name property.

A better approach to do this would be this though:

```
gci test.* | select name
```

Why do you want to turn it into a string that kills the pipelines's object oriented paramater binding?

Edit:

The better approach is to output stuff to a file like this:

```
foreach($file in (gci test.*)) 
{
    ("Name: {0} is here {1}" -f $file.name,$file.fullname) | out-file C:\temp\log.txt -Append -Encoding utf8
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why it thinks I want FullName instead of Name, when I've explicitly chosen '$_.Name'?

Comment: I want the string for reasons. This was a simple example of the problem, in my actual use case I'm outputting the name within other text into an output file.

Comment: It expands $_ as object and returns the fullname attribute. It doesn't recognize .name and just treats it as a regular string that will be appended to the returned fullname attribute.

Comment: Oh, of course. I hadn't even noticed the trailing '.Name' in my question output, I was so focused on the path. d'uh. Thanks.